# Live Filtering in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am looking to implement a live filtering feature to my site which will filter through a full list of contacts in real time when a user begins to type either the contact name or contact company.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions of add ins/code that would already complete this?

I have looked at Elastic Search and Solr but neither seem appropriate for what I want to do.

Thanks for any suggestions you have!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have a look at this gem!

[autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete)

Comment: you need to fetch the onchange and then filter your list or collection